# В один из праздников Нового года

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли как-то иначе оформить эту фразу, говоря о событии, случившемся в одно из празднований?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше звучит так:
*в один [на одном] из новогодних праздников;

в один из дней празднования Нового года*. || В конце предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, подойдёт ли такое: *Как-то раз в новогоднюю ночь...* Или *в новогодний день/вечер.*

Answer (score 1):

*Однажды* зимою, *в канун новогодних праздников*, в Петербурге, у Юсуповского дворца на Мойке, появились два гражданина со свёрнутым ковром.

Comment: Но канун - это день, предшествующий празднику, а не сам праздник.

Comment: Это лишь реалистичный пример - дело было 30 числа. А в исходной формулировке из вопроса можно и впрямь запутаться: я сначала подумал, что это "один из праздников" за время новогодних каникул (между ранним и поздним Рождеством).